# Rust type inferencing oddity

Tags: rust, type-inference

I ran into a weird situation earlier. I wrote:

```
if rand::random() < self.food_chance {...}
```

(`self.food_chance` is of type `f32`)

and I got a type inferencing error:

```
   |
71 |             if rand::random() < self.food_chance {
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
```

However this code compiles

```
if self.food_chance > rand::random() {...}
```

And I'm left wondering. Is there a reason for this behaviour?
Is it even intended behaviour?

I know a little bit about type inferencing theory, and I know that most of the algorithms are agnostic to lhs/rhs, so I'm tempted to think this is expected behaviour rather than straight up a bug.

I tried searching around, but I never got anything close to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's basically because Rust can never infer the type of the receiver. The type of the receiver must be known to perform method lookup, and since

```
rand::random() < self.food_chance
```

is equivalent to

```
std::cmp::PartialOrd::lt(&rand::random(), &self.food_chance);
```

the receiver is the left-hand operand.

In the expression

```
self.food_chance > rand::random()
```

on the other hand, the receiver is known, so Rust can perform method lookup. It will only find a single implementation for `f32` as the receiver, namely `PartialOrd<f32>`, which then in turn determines the type of the right-hand side. If there were implementations for different right-hand side types, Rust would not be able to infer the type in that case either.

To understand *why* Rust can't infer the receiver, take a look at [how Rust's method lookup process works](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html). The first step is to build a list of candidate types based on the type of the receiver. This obvious only works when you already *know* the type of the receiver.

Comment: Would you happen to know if this is a limitation of the language (impossible to resolve otherwise) or merely a limitation of the current implementation?

Comment: @MatthieuM. The current language definition simply does not contain a process for inferring the type of the receiver. The definition of the method lookup process (see link in the answer) certainly requires that the type of the receiver is known in advance. If we wanted to infer the type of the receiver, we would need to invent different method lookup semantics for the case that the receiver is not known. I can't think of any reasonable and consistent way of defining semantics for this.

Comment: I think it should be possible by treating all arguments equally; select a list of candidate methods by simple name look-up (inherent + visible traits), then use inference on receiver & argument to find which candidate could match, reject if there's any ambiguity. What I am not sure of is whether there are cases were the algorithmic complexity would explode, making it pratically impossible to resolve.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You probably could define a language with these semantics, but it would be quite different from Rust.

Comment: I may be naive, but I don't see any *semantic* difference here; just a difference in how to infer the types.

Comment: @MatthieuM. There are several problems. First, trait implementations can be generic, so it's simply not possible to find _all_ implementations of a method in scope – there may be an infinite number of them. The second problem is that the current mechanism looks up methods on a list of candidate types _in a particular order_, and the first match is used. It is only an error if there is an ambiguity for a single type. The third problem is that the receiver is treated differently in other respects than type inference as well, so treating it the same as other arguments would change semantics.

Answer (score 3):

The `>` operator is sugar for a method; the [`partial_cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cmp.rs.html#903-910) method of the [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cmp.rs.html#198) trait. The method is called with the left-hand side as the `self` argument; this determines which implementation of `PartialOrd` is used. Because you could implement the `PartialOrd` trait for different types with `f32` as the right-hand side type, the implementation of `PartialOrd` is only uniquely determined if the type of the left-hand side is known. This implementation of `PartialOrd`, in turn, determines the type required from `rand::random`.

Comment: You argue that there could be different types with `f32` as right-hand side, while there can be only one implementation with `f32` as left-hand side. This is not true, as you can see [in this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=2acb93d1887f678fec966acb72cbd8ba). There is only a single implementation with `f32` as left-hand side, but there is also only a single implementation with `f32` as right-hand side, so I can't really see how this answer explains the assymetry.

Comment: My argument assumes that the OP doesn't manually implement `PartialOrd` for `f32`, in which case OP should have mentioned this, as it is relevant for the question. This is a reason the compiler is able to infer the type. I didn't state that there could be only one implementation of `PartialOrd` with `f32` as the left-hand side. Your example does however nicely demonstrate your answer.